# I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'Invoice/a.pdf': No such file or directory

Tags: python, io

I am trying to read some data from an invoice.

my `test.py`:

```
from invoice2data import extract_data
from invoice2data.extract.loader import read_templates

templates = read_templates('template/a.pdf')
print(templates)

result = extract_data('Invoice/a.pdf', templates=templates)
print(result)
```

Here my base folder has the following structure:

```
 |template
 |      | a.pdf
 |
 |Invoice
 |      | a.pdf
 |
 |test.py
```

but it says the following error:

```
[]
I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'Invoice/a.pdf': No such file or directory.
False
No template for Invoice/a.pdf
[Finished in 1.399s]
```

How can I fix it? I must need to use [invoice2data 0.3.5](https://pypi.org/project/invoice2data/)

Comment: did you try with absolute path?

Comment: Your current working directory (see [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd)) may not be the folder where you have your test.py script. It all depends on how you run your script.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to put the directory in.

templates = read_templates('**template/a.pdf**')

Try putting the path into that area.
(r'{PATH}')

Or make the file in the editor.